# App working fine on adb debug, but crash after deploy apk to phone

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, locationmanager

I'm newbie on xamarin, so I took the BackgroundlocationDemo example from the tutorials and changed a couple of things. Basically to connect to an api when location change.

It works fine using vs usb debugging on my phone, but when I deploy the apk, and install on the same phone it crashes (not sure is when it gets the location or when post to the api), with no error, just "Application has stopped" message.

Not sure how to debug that, or see where is the problem, or get any information from the crash on the phone.

I appreciate you help in advance to point me in the right direction.

Comment: did you add permission for location at runtime for marshmallow??

Comment: Yes...  I did it  Don't need any special permission to make a http post? Right?

Comment: You know what, you can upload it to play store in a CLOSED alpha/beta testing so nobody can see it but you (and people you allow) and see if it crashes. If it does, click on **send error report** and you'll get a log of the error!

Comment: It seems to have a $25 cost. It is a bit expensive to debug an error.  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone pointed me to use the Android device logging (logcat), and run the app from the phone, instead of VS.

So doing that I got this output:

```
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): Process: Location.Droid, PID: 2986
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): ... 1 more
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal (System.Uri address, System.String method, System.Byte[] data, System.Net.WebRequest& request) [0x000a6] in :0
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString (System.Uri address, System.String method, System.String data) [0x00054] in :0
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString (System.String address, System.String data) [0x00019] in :0
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.WebClient:UploadString (string,string)
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at Location.Droid.Services.LocationService.OnLocationChanged (Android.Locations.Location location) [0x00157] in :0
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at Android.Locations.ILocationListenerInvoker.n_OnLocationChanged_Landroid_location_Location_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_location) [0x00011] in :0
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:cad3edbb-2ed8-4cac-ad94-e74d5e046d4e (intptr,intptr,intptr)
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at md5227b9e8295fbee87e0da67869d6e828e.LocationService.n_onLocationChanged(Native Method)
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at md5227b9e8295fbee87e0da67869d6e828e.LocationService.onLocationChanged(LocationService.java:68)
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:281)
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:210)
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:226)
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-01 00:44:40.431 E/AndroidRuntime( 2986): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
```

So, It seems to be an issue resolving the url. After a bit of research I figured out that I need to give INTERNET permission to the app.